# how to access the hash elements which have both hash reference and array references

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a hash which contains few levels of hashes which has array and hash references.
So I have written a code like the one below to access both using output of `ref($var)`.
The `%c` is my hash. After 3rd level of for loop I am getting hash reference and array reference so I want to access the array elements.
I am using `my $array_ref = [%$new_values];` in my else loop to access the array elements.
But I am getting below error:

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not array dereference)
```

## My code:

```
foreach my $item ( keys %c ) {
    print "$item: \n";    # print keys
    my $hash = $c{$item};

    foreach my $key2 ( keys %$hash ) {
        print "\t", $key2, "\n\t";    # print keys
        my $hashref = $hash->{$key2};
        my $myref = ref($hashref);
        #print("ref type is $myref\n");

        foreach my $key3 (keys %{$hashref}) {
            my $values = $hashref->{$key3};
            my $myref1 = ref($values);
            # print("ref type is $myref1\n");

            foreach my $key4 (keys %{$values}) {
                my $new_values = $values->{$key4};
                my $myref2 = ref($new_values);
                if ($myref2 eq HASH) {
                     #print("ref type is $myref2\n");
                     print "\t", join "\t", map { %$_ } %$new_values;    
                     print "\n";
                }
                elsif ($myref2 eq ARRAY) {
                    print "\t", join "\t", map { @$_ } @$new_values; 
                    print "\n";
                    my $array_ref = [%$new_values];
                    my $new_type = ref($array_ref);
                    print "$new_type\n";
                    foreach my $key_array ( keys @$array_ref) {
                        print "$key_array\n";
                    }
                    print "\t", $key_array, "\n\t";     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program, especially if you are asking for help with it

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
print "\t", join "\t", map { %$_ } %$new_values;
```

and

```
print "\t", join "\t", map { @$_ } @$new_values;
```

contain *two* dereferences instead of one, and `map {...}, %hash` will pass all the keys and values to the block, so an attempt to dereference a key inside the block will always fail as it cannot be a reference.

It isn't clear exactly what these should be. Presumably you just want a list of the values in the case that `$new_values` is an array reference, so you want

```
print "\t", join "\t", @$new_values;
```

or just

```
print "\t$_" for @$new_values;
```

but in the case of the hash, do you want to see the keys or just the values? If it is the latter then you should write

```
print "\t", join "\t", values %$new_values;
```

but there are many ways to dump both the key and value for each hash element. Here's a suggestion

```
print "\t", join ', ', map "$_ => '$new_values->{$_}'", keys %$new_values;
```

I can't understand what it is you're intending in your last section

```
my $array_ref = [%$new_values];
my $new_type = ref($array_ref);
print "$new_type\n";
foreach my $key_array ( keys @$array_ref) {
   print "$key_array\n";
}
print "\t", $key_array, "\n\t";
```

but it is clear that your attempt to dereference `$new_values` as a hash in `my $array_ref = [%$new_values]` will fail, as this is within a block where you have confirmed that `$new_values` is an *array* reference.

Also, the line `my $new_type = ref($array_ref)` seems superfluous as you have just created `$array_ref` as an array reference, so `$new_type` will *always* be `ARRAY`.

Finally, your `for` loop over `keys @$array_ref` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Before version 12 of Perl 5 it was a syntax error, but since then it will return the list of array indices, so it is the same as `0 .. $#$array_ref`.

If you explain this section a little better then I will gladly help you to get it working.